# C# Get Certificate from CA standalone

Tags: c#, certificate, x509certificate

I have a standalone CA and I need to get a full certificate base64 string using C# searching by certificate serial number.

Already tried using X509Store, tried with CA name, hostname\ca-name, and all StoreName and StoreLocation possible variations

```
store = new X509Store("my-ca");
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
ret += "Count: " + store.Certificates.Count;
foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in store.Certificates)
{
    ret += "cert.SerialNumber: " + cert.SerialNumber;
}
```

And also tried with CCertView/CCertRequest, this method is returning information, but it's not the full certificate, the string is not equal when I manually export from CA.

```
public string GetCertificateBase64Original(string certificateSerialNumber)
{
    string certificateBase64 = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        CCertView certView = new CCertViewClass();
        certView.OpenConnection(this.nameCA);

        certView.SetResultColumnCount(2);

        int requestIDColumnIndex = certView.GetColumnIndex(0, "RequestID");
        int certificateSerialNumberColumnIndex = certView.GetColumnIndex(0, "SerialNumber");

        certView.SetResultColumn(requestIDColumnIndex);
        certView.SetResultColumn(certificateSerialNumberColumnIndex);

        object objSerialNumber = certificateSerialNumber;

        certView.SetRestriction(certificateSerialNumberColumnIndex, CVR_SEEK_EQ, CVR_SORT_NONE, ref objSerialNumber);

        IEnumCERTVIEWROW rowsEnum;
        rowsEnum = certView.OpenView();

        IEnumCERTVIEWCOLUMN objCol;
        rowsEnum.Reset();

        int requestID = 0;

        while (rowsEnum.Next() != -1)
        {
            objCol = rowsEnum.EnumCertViewColumn();

            while (objCol.Next() != -1)
            {
                if (objCol.GetName() == "RequestID")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        requestID = SafeConvert.ToInt(objCol.GetValue(PROPTYPE_STRING));
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (requestID > 0)
        {
            CCertRequest certRequest = new CCertRequest();

            certRequest.GetIssuedCertificate(this.nameCA, requestID, certificateSerialNumber);

            certificateBase64 = SafeConvert.ToString(certRequest.GetFullResponseProperty(FR_PROP_FULLRESPONSE, 0, PROPTYPE_BINARY, CR_OUT_BASE64));
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    return (certificateBase64);
}
```

No success at all.

Comment: Please start by reading [ask] and posting a [MCVE]

Comment: Where is your code running in relation to the CA?

Comment: Code samples added. @CamiloTerevinto

Comment: @bartonjs this code is running on a webservice at the same machine of my ca.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using this code

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2012/04/04/how-to-export-issued-certificates-from-a-ca-programatically-c/
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2010/05/10/how-to-get-info-from-client-certificates-issued-by-a-ca-c/

```
public string GetCertificateBase64(string certificateSerialNumber)
{
    string certificateBase64 = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        // Variables
        CERTADMINLib.CCertView certView = null;
        CERTADMINLib.IEnumCERTVIEWROW certViewRow = null;
        CERTADMINLib.IEnumCERTVIEWCOLUMN certViewColumn = null;
        int iColumnCount = 0;
        object objValue = null;

        // Connecting to the Certificate Authority
        certView = new CERTADMINLib.CCertView();
        certView.OpenConnection(this.nameCA);

        // Get a column count and place columns into the view
        iColumnCount = certView.GetColumnCount(0);
        certView.SetResultColumnCount(iColumnCount);

        // Place each column in the view.
        for (int x = 0; x < iColumnCount; x++)
        {
            certView.SetResultColumn(x);
        }

        int certificateSerialNumberColumnIndex = certView.GetColumnIndex(0, "SerialNumber");
        object objSerialNumber = certificateSerialNumber;
        certView.SetRestriction(certificateSerialNumberColumnIndex, CVR_SEEK_EQ, CVR_SORT_NONE, ref objSerialNumber);

        // Open the View and reset the row position
        certViewRow = certView.OpenView();
        certViewRow.Reset();

        // Enumerate Row and Column Information

        // Rows (one per cert) 
        for (int x = 0; certViewRow.Next() != -1; x++)
        {
            // Columns with the info we need
            certViewColumn = certViewRow.EnumCertViewColumn();
            while (certViewColumn.Next() != -1)
            {
                switch (certViewColumn.GetDisplayName())
                {
                    // Binary Certificate
                    case "Binary Certificate":
                        objValue = certViewColumn.GetValue(CV_OUT_BASE64);
                        if (objValue != null)
                        {
                            certificateBase64 = objValue.ToString();
                        }
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        certificateBase64 += Environment.NewLine + "ex: " + ex.Message;
    }

    return certificateBase64;
}
```

Comment: Also look at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2012/04/04/how-to-get-info-from-client-certificates-issued-by-a-ca-c-vs-2010/ particularly if it chokes at `CERTADMINLib`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are requesting `FR_PROP_FULLRESPONSE` property that contains full response (IIRC, a PKCS#7 message). Instead, you should request only issued certificate property: `FR_PROP_ISSUEDCERTIFICATE`.

BTW `ICertRequest` interface call is not necessary. Why not to put `RawCertificate` column to the result column list in `ICertView` interface calls and then grab the result?

Comment: This is a 2009 code that never worked and someone wants to use now, I'm just trying to make it work, I'm not the original dev, so, I don't know why he did some things.
And this code seens to run only on 2003 server, I don't know why, but this do not work on my 2012 + CA server.
Will try now change FR_PROP_FULLRESPONSE for FR_PROP_ISSUEDCERTIFICATE (private const int FR_PROP_ISSUEDCERTIFICATE = 11;)

Comment: Will try to use objCol.GetName() == "RawCertificate"

Comment: Do not forget to add this column to the output column list.